# Authcache settings for blocks or views in panels

Tags: 7, caching

I am setting up Authcache ESI and Varnish on Drupal 7. My site has panel pages that incorporate personalized blocks and views. Authcache allows caching parameters to be specified for blocks or views, and also on panels.

What is the recommended approach in this case? For example if I am placing a view in a panel page, should I:

- Specify Authcache settings for the view only?
- Specify Authcache settings for the view panel within the panel page only?
- Specify Authcache settings for both the view and the panel -- and if I specify settings
  for both, which takes precedence?

Answer (score 1):

Note that each fragment which is loaded from the server results in an additional request. Hence it is beneficial to minimize the amount of fragments and it follows that you should pack all your personalized panes into one request if possible.

Note also that you only can load panels/panes if you place them with page manager. Neither Panelizer nor Mini Panels are supported at the moment ([see](https://www.drupal.org/node/2293285) [these](https://www.drupal.org/node/2231701) [issues](https://www.drupal.org/node/2703789))

You should not nest authcache fragments. If you do then, the outer most wins. Authcache will not add any fragment placeholders inside fragments loaded via Ajax/ESI.

Comment: Thanks @znerol. Fortunately I am using page manager, not Panelizer or Mini Panels. If I understand you correctly, if I put Authcache settings on a view pane and then include that view pane in a panel that has Authcache settings, the view pane Authcache settings will be ignored. Can you expand please on what you meant by "pack all your personalized panes into one request"?

Comment: Design your site in a way that minimizes the amount of fragment requests. E.g., group personalized information into one view/panel/block instead of placing multiple separate ones.